# What are topics needed to develop web application in scala?

Tags: html, scala, tomcat, playframework, akka

I am good in java and recently learning scala. I want to develop web application. what are the concepts of scala I need to learn?

Comment: Read a book on scala, try by yourself, and come back here to ask questions on specific problems you run into. See [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Welcome on SO by the way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really nothing specific about Scala and web apps. I would recommend starting with reading play documentation (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Home) and asking specific questions about stuff you don't understand. Or reading a book on Scala.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest to give a try to the [Spray](http://spray.io/) toolkit for creating RESTful web-services. It's pretty good for a java developer